# <error reading variable> when trying to follow the variable with watchpoint

Tags: c, gdb

When I try to follow a program for debugging purposes, my GDB fails to show how variable changes.

I tried to install different versions of GDB, but still got the same issue.

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from C:\Users\china\Documents\LU\SCC.150\practicals\week20\mystrtest.exe...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401602: file mystrtest.c, line 26.
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\china\Documents\LU\SCC.150\practicals\week20/mystrtest.exe
[New Thread 21152.0x4fa8]
[New Thread 21152.0x5670]

Breakpoint 1, main () at mystrtest.c:26
26              char test_string_1[] = "hello world!";
(gdb) watch test_string_1
Hardware watchpoint 2: test_string_1
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: test_string_1

Old value = <error reading variable>
New value = <error reading variable>
0x00401612 in main () at mystrtest.c:26
26              char test_string_1[] = "hello world!";
(gdb)
```

I wanted to see the old and new states of the variables, instead of getting an error.

Comment: the variable might be optimized out by the compiler. Compile with -Og  and -g3

Comment: Tried, still got the same issue

C:\Users\china\Documents\LU\SCC.150\practicals\week20>gcc -g3 -Og mystring.c mystrtest.c -o mystrtest
...
Hardware watchpoint 2: test_string_1

Old value = <error reading variable>
New value = <error reading variable>
0x004014b9 in main () at mystrtest.c:26
26              char test_string_1[] = "hello world!";

Comment: show the code ..

Comment: `C:\Users\china\Documents\LU\SCC.150\practicals\week20>gcc -g3 -Og mystring.c mystrtest.c -o mystrtest` ... `Hardware watchpoint 2: test_string_1 Old value = <error reading variable> New value = <error reading variable> 0x004014b9 in main () at mystrtest.c:26 26 char test_string_1[] = "hello world!";`